# ReferenceError: window is not defined . vuepress

Tags: webpack, vuepress

I use `canvas-nest.js` in the vuepress (import CanvasNest from 'canvas-nest.js') it works when I use `yarn dev`; but it gives an error when I use `yarn build`:

```
Rendering static HTML...
Rendering page: / FAIL  Error rendering /:ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/canvas-nest.js/lib/utils.js:11:0)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
    at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (node_modules/canvas-nest.
js/lib/CanvasNest.js:16:0)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
    at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (node_modules/canvas-nest.
js/lib/index.js:7:0)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Seems like a common issue (fighting with same thing now) and not much good info out there on fixing fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue importing scrollmagic. I resolved by by component not importing the scripts with import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic' as usual but using const ScrollMagic = require('scrollmagic') in a methods function requested via the mounted hook. eg.

```
<script>
import { TweenMax, TimelineMax, Sine } from 'gsap'
DO NOT MAKE WINDOW IMPORT REQUESTS HERE
// import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
// import 'animation.gsap'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
     box:'.box'
     };
  },
methods: { 
    animate(){
      const ScrollMagic = require('scrollmagic') 
      const animationGsap = require('@dk-animationGsap') 

      const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
        let tween = new TimelineMax ()
            .add([
          TweenMax.staggerFromTo(this.box, 0.5, {autoAlpha:0,y:-200,scale:0.9}, {autoAlpha:1,y:100,scale:1,ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.75)}, 1)
         ]);

      const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerHook: 'onEnter',
          duration: 400,    
          offset: 0
        })
        .setTween(tween)
        .addTo(controller);
    }
  },
  mounted() { 
   this.animate()
  },

}
</script>
```